# Extracting hidden image in matlab using least significant bit

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, byte, bit

So I'm trying to solve this problem but its been giving me what I think isn't the correct answer. Since every time i tried it would give me a new image.

Here is the problem:
[image]

Here is the image they provided us in BMP format ([link for BMP download](http://www.mediafire.com/download/6nec6setjillxel/question1.bmp)):
[image]

And here's what I've tried, or have been trying with no result so far:

[image]

So I made the entire 512x512 matrix a single vector so that i can extract the LSB from each pixel and then regroup every 8 into 1.

var1 is the vector form of the cdata matrix containing values from 0 to 255.
var2 is the least significant bit of each number, obtained by applying the modulus/remainder function by the division by 2.
var3 groups every 8 cells into 1 row and forms a matrix of (171^2)*8
var4 converts the matrix into a String array of characters
var5 converts each row in the string array into its corresponding number from binary to decimal
final puts it back into a 171*171 matrix.
imshow displays the data as an image, (I can also do imshow(final,colormap) but it won't change the picture much)

I'm suppose to get a recognizable picture, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've looked all around the web for another way to do this with no luck. So stackoverflow was my last option.

EDIT: Here's the code

```
uiopen('D:\Users\Desktop\rally\question1.bmp',1) %gives cdata array (512*512) and colormap array (256*3)
var1 = cdata( : );
var2 = rem(var1,2);
var2 = var2(121:233928+120);
var3 = vec2mat(var2',8);
var4 = num2str(var3);
var5 = bin2dec(var4);
final = vec2mat(var5,171);
imshow(final)
```

Comment: dear G'd in heaven! read the image using `imread` and NOT using `uiopen`!!!!

Comment: I just dragged and dropped the image :v  | 
it gave me the colormap and cdata arrays   | 
what's the difference?

Comment: @ThaBomb: Please provide your code as a text. I can't read it that small on the screenshot.

Comment: Added the code, the screenshot is pretty big if you right click > view image btw.

Comment: I'll bet the problem was using `uiopen`. Because when I read in the image with `imread`, it comes in as 512x512 and not 512x512x3...

Comment: its not a 512x512x3, 
It comes out as a 512x512 with uiopen, and you can see it fine in the last image.
Also I tried it with imread aswell and it gave me the same result.

Comment: Using `uiopen` is weird, but it is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some heavy reverse engineering I was able to liberate a 171 x 171 grayscale version of Lena from your BMP. However, the description you were given is wrong in several respects, and unclear in others.

– The original image data have to be used sequentially, but not in Matlab's column-by-column way but in the normal image bitmap storage format, row-by-row. We therefore need a transpose:

```
A = imread('question1.bmp');
A = A';
```

– Data amounting to 120 pixels have to be skipped, but not from the beginning of the original image. We rather need to decode the least significant bits of *all* pixels, packing them into 8-bit bytes where the most significant bit is the first:

```
bits = rem(A, 2);
bits = reshape(bits, 8, []);
bytes = 2 .^ fliplr(0 : 7) * single(bits);
```

– Weirdly, the resulting byte sequence is organized in chunks of 64 bytes length:

```
data = reshape(bytes, 64, 512);
```

– The resulting matrix turns out to be organized in reversed column-row-order (we need to transpose again), and from the resulting sequence we need to skip 15 pixels (corresponding to 120 bits) at the beginning, and reshape to 171 x 171:

```
data = data';
I = reshape(data(16 : 171 * 171 + 15), 171, 171)';
```

Interestingly, the 15 bytes to be skipped contain the ASCII test "messageStart " followed by two bytes with values 171 and 171.

– With this, a familiar face is recovered:

```
imagesc(I)
axis image
colormap gray
```

[image: Lena]

Don't ask me how I figured this out, just give me the up-votes! ;-)
(Hint: looking at autocorrelation functions helped…)

Comment: Thank you so much, I had a feeling their instructions were terribly wrong somehow :)  
Well done.

Comment: There's another one of the same type, except I have to extract a text instead.
If you want to help me solve it, I'd gladly link the image and instructions

Comment: I think it's enough for me for today. If you post it as a question I might have a look at it later. Did you see my last edit, where I mention that the skipped bytes have a text interpretation? That might help...

Comment: Yes I got that, but I can't seem to understand how you skipped the 120 pixels where you said you had to decode them because they aren't sequential.
How do you skip the 120 pixels/bits in your code?